# What do I need to create an app that summarizes text from a document (include 100-150 characters)?

Tags: android, algorithm, summary

I want to create an feature which can summarizes text from a document in Android.

I am confusion about algorithm to do it

Any support from anyone will be appreciate

Comment: This isn't really something we can answer.  Even if you keep the problem to a single language (like English), you're either just going to take the first 150 characters, or you're going to have to do linguistic analysis of the text which is a non-trivial task that's the center of millions of dollars of research.

Comment: I vote to close this question as it is too broad, and does not ask a specific thing.  i also agree with @GabeSechan that it should be something very complex to do.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done. If you are writing on your own, you have to start with nltk library for java which is abbreviated as Natural language tool kit, which allows you to carry out these kind of text summarization.  or you can use the following open source code to carry out , what you want.

Like, how many no. of words your summarizing content should have at final. Have a look at it.

https://github.com/mohaps/tldrzr